# How to check certain coordinates on a point cloud / 3d object?

Tags: python, c++, image-processing, 3d, point-cloud-library

I have a point cloud of a human body and 3d scan of it. I have some coordinates of skeleton joints but I want to check if the coordinates fit the body/point cloud or not.

I have tried to do that with python open3d and pangolin c++ but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

I have X, Y, Z coordinates of a point and I want to see where it is in my point cloud. To explain my question I have an example image that is done with paint.

[image: perfect art]

I need advice about what I can use to do that.

Comment: If you can reconstruct a concave hull from the point cloud, you can shoot a ray from your test point to a random position and count the number of triangle intersections. If it is odd you are inside the hull.

Comment: You can use [pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudSearch](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1octree_1_1_octree_point_cloud_search.html) class and use `voxelSearch` function.  If the given point is inside the voxel, the function will return `true`, `false` otherwise.

Comment: @Botje i will try thank you

Comment: @kanstar okey i will try it. also i couldn't figure out how to use pcl with python but it works with c++. What language do you recommend for pcl?

Comment: i also want to see the exact location of my point like in the picture. I want to see is it on hand, head or chest etc.

Comment: You can use the `visualization` module of `PCL`. Have a look at this [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if you want to check visually or automatically.

The visually check is very easy to do with Open3D (at least, installation is much easier than PCL-Python)

First, you need to install open3d packages. Then read your point clouds by:

```py
import open3d as o3d
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(file_path)
```

Then generate two red point cloud in o3d: # I think your x(3,1) means x for two points

```py
import numpy as np

pcd_red = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()

xyz = np.asarray([[3, 2, 8],
                  [1, 8, 3]])

pcd_red.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(xyz)

# paint them to red
pcd_red.paint_uniform_color([1, 0, 0])
```

Finally is display:

```py
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd, pcd_red])
```